# Restricting perverse intermediate extension to closed complement

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves, derived-functors

Consider a scheme $X$ over athe complex numbers, $j:U\to X$ an open subscheme, $i:Z\to X$ its closed complement, and a perverse sheaf $F$ over $U$ with complex coefficients.

The intermediate extension $j_{!*}F$ is again a perverse sheaf, and is different from both $j_!F$ and $j_*F$. Let us now consider the pullback $i^*j_{!*}F$.

> **Question**: is it true that $i^*j_{!*}F\simeq i^*j_*F$?

Comment: I think the answer is negative already for the (shifted) constant sheaf on $\mathbf{A}^1\setminus 0$? In this case $j_{!*} \mathbf{Z}[1] = \mathbf{Z}[1]$ while your right hand side has nonzero zeroth cohomology?

Comment: True, thanks! Related to this: is there any base change theorem for intermediate extensions? Something like: you have a Cartesian square where the vertical maps are open embeddings, and you perform pullback along the horizontal maps and intermediate extensions along the vertical maps.

Comment: I think such a base change statement should hold, as open pullback is exact, so preserves images, and one can apply your open pullback to the morphism $j_!$ to $j_*$, and use base change.

Comment: Actually the open maps would be the other ones in my example... but thanks anyway, this is still good to know!